# how to create smooth transparency by png transparency

Tags: transparency

I have already tried many different ways, read the material, but I have not found the answer to my question.

I want the transparency to match the PNG image,

[image]

but I get cropped

[image]

UPDATE:
I have already change blend mode to "blend", I get a strange transparency of the whole object

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eevee the transparency settings are tricky. Choose *Blend Mode > Alpha Blend* instead of *Alpha Clip*, to avoid the artefacts disable the *Show Backface* option:

[image]

Comment: I have already tried, I get a strange transparency of the whole object

Comment: could you please pack your image (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file?

Comment: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/ZzE8SGZpjJE1Vg

Comment: it seems to work fine, in Alpha Blend mode it is not copletely transparent because you still have some colors, you can remove it in the Image Editor with a brush that is set to Erase Alpha. As for the back face, enable Backface Culling option

Comment: ok, thx, i'll try this